# U-Boot issue..Early serial print continously getting printing

Tags: arm, u-boot

am trying to port u-boot to my custom board with micrel ks8692 Soc. 
I got u-boot from micrel, which i modified for my board. Made an image and put inside the flash. I couldnt get any data in hyperterminal after rebooting. I tried some serial port prints(push data in serial TX register) in the lowlevel init code

code flow is

1. Set clock and system regs
2. init uart
3. debug serial print added by me ( letters A and B)
4. DDR initialization
5. Flash remapping

After this am getting contious ABABABABAB....in the hyperterminal.I think code went in loop is not going out of lowlevel init. Please help me to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your board is crashing during flow steps 4 or 5, restarting init, that is the loop. Move letter B output further out into flow step 4 or 5, to see where is the crash, then fix that.

If you can get a JTAG debugger your life will be much easier.

Comment: Dear sir, i fixed the issue. It was due to issue in flash remapping.